# How to create 32 crores pages XML sitemap for HTML website

Tags: sitemap, xml

I have created an HTML website having 32 crore pages on it. this is a flight booking website. Now I want to create an xml sitemap for this and implement

Comment: There are too many ways to implement a sitemap to list them all here.